# MongoDB : Group different fields with same common values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I need to perform an aggregate on a mongodb collection. But I can't find the correct aggregation pipeline.

In fact, I need to get IDs of different documents when `doc1.fieldTarget == doc2.fieldSource && doc2.fieldTarget == doc3.fieldSource`

For example I want to find all documents when the target(docA) is the same than the source (of docB) and then verify if his target is the source of any other documents

It's about finding the target server by port numbers.

Sample docs:

```
 [{
    _id: 11,
    portSource: 1,
    portTarget: 2,
    status:active
  },
  {
    _id: 22,
    portSource: 2,
    portTarget: 3
    status:passive
  },
  {
    _id: 33,
    portSource: 3,
    portTarget: 10
    status:active
  },
   {
    _id: 44,
    portSource: 3,
    portTarget: 5
    status:passive
  },
 {
    _id: 55,
    portSource: 5,
    portTarget: 7
    status:active
  },
 {
    _id: 66,
    portSource: 12,
    portTarget: 4
    status:active
  },
 {
    _id: 77,
    portSource: 4,
    portTarget: 16
    status:passive
  },
 {
    _id: 88,
    portSource: 4,
    portTarget: 246
    status:active
  },
 {
    _id: 99,
    portSource: 246,
    portTarget: 500
    status:active
  },
]
```

**My desired outpout:**

```
[
 {
  portSource: 1, portTarget: 10, sourceId : 11, targetId: 33
 },
 {
  portSource: 1, portTarget: 7, sourceId : 11, targetId: 55
 }
]
```

It looks like the segment addition postulate (AB+BC=AC).

If there is a "B" then tell me that we have a connections between "A" and "C"

**Note 1:** The path can usually look like AB+BC+CD or more and the desired result is A->D as shown in the example with `id:11 && id:55`

**Note 2:** `id:66` isn't returned because the port 16 of `id:77` doesn't match to a potential "C"

**Note 3:** `id:66` isn't returned because `id:88` is not a passive "B"

Thanks you !